How do I get rid of the annoying terminal warning when using Gemini API?
I followed all the docs for the Gemini API, however, I cannot find anything that solves this issue.
https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/quickstart?lang=python
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1721615745.026734   20796 config.cc:230] gRPC experiments enabled: call_status_override_on_cancellation, event_engine_client, event_engine_dns, event_engine_listener, http2_stats_fix, monitoring_experiment, pick_first_new, trace_record_callops, work_serializer_clears_time_cache

This is the code that generates this warning (the AI runs fine it's just annoying)
import google.generativeai as genai
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

def main(): 
    load_dotenv()
    key = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_API_KEY')
    genai.configure(api_key=key)
    genai.configure(transport='grpc')

    model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')
    response = model.generate_content("message")

    print(response.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



related? https://github.com/google-ai-edge/mediapipe/issues/5371

You could try running it, but redirecting stderr to /dev/null. You could use another python script to do that.

These annoying terminal warnings are generated by the underlying libraries (gRPC and Abseil) of Gemini while initializing logging configurations. To suppress them, set these environment variables to control their logging levels:
import os

# Suppress logging warnings
os.environ["GRPC_VERBOSITY"] = "ERROR"
os.environ["GLOG_minloglevel"] = "2"

Setting:

GRPC_VERBOSITY="ERROR": Limits gRPC logs to errors only.
GLOG_minloglevel="2": Limits Google logging (used by Abseil) to errors only.
(0: INFO, 1: WARNING, 2: ERROR, 3: FATAL)

Using this configuration, you can suppress less severe log messages, including warnings, resulting in a cleaner terminal output.
Hope this helps!

Also, if you encounter the following warning when using the Gemini API:
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1732812807.208491    8110 init.cc:229] grpc_wait_for_shutdown_with_timeout() timed out.


This issue is caused by the version of grpcio used. To fix it, simply downgrade to a stable version:
pip install grpcio==1.60.1


grpcio==1.60.1: This version avoids the grpc_wait_for_shutdown_with_timeout() warning, which is triggered by some newer versions of the library.

Using this solution will help you get rid of the warning and result in a cleaner terminal output.
Thank me later! 

is it safe to ignore this warning?

for me installing a stable version of grpcio worked
pip install grpcio==1.60.1


In python 3.12.4 or python 3.10.13 bistro,
You might use grpcio==1.68.1 and grpcio-status==1.68.1.
Downgrading grpcio and grpcio-status to version 1.67.1 resolves your warning problem clearly.
pip install grpcio==1.67.1 grpcio-status==1.67.1 


Another way to suppress the terminal warnings generated by the Gemini API is to set the transport to 'rest' in the genai.configure function like the example below:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import google.generativeai as genai

def main():
    load_dotenv()
    key = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_API_KEY')
    
    # Configure transport as 'rest'
    genai.configure(api_key=key, transport='rest')
    model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')
    response = model.generate_content("message")
    print(response.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


That line solved the case for me:
pip install grpcio==1.60.1

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/79244491/10721627.
