GCP pub-sub errors
I am building a simple webapp that accepts HTTP POSTs and should trigger a Cloud Pub-Sub event. Without pub-sub, the app deploys fine and I can reach the endpoint.
I've created a sample functions. I've done this both through Cloud Run Functions (console.cloud.google.com/functions/). This shows Deployed By as "Cloud Run Functions" and through Cloud Run (i.e. console.cloud.google.com/run). This shows Deployed By as my account. Same outcomes.
For the initial pre-packaged hello world example, both deploy no problem.
Now let's add the pub-sub capability. Add google-cloud-pubsub to the requirements file. Add the pub-sub client to the app. Create a Pub-Sub topic (which I do via the UI).
So now it looks like this...
import json
import os
import functions_framework
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

PROJECT_ID = "my project"
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic}'.format(
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        topic='test-topic',
    )
    message = {
        'key': 'value',
        'info': 'This is a test message'
    }
    future = publisher.publish(topic_name, json.dumps(message).encode("utf-8"))
    future.result()

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(name)


I'll reliably get these warnings in the console. What do they mean?

WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1734272617.454893 1 init.cc:229] grpc_wait_for_shutdown_with_timeout() timed out.

Additionally, I'll get weird errors in in the Google Cloud Platform Run testing console that look to be build related (e.g. the /bin/sh: 2c3d685a15e9). Sometimes it errors, sometimes it does not.
[9:47:15 PM] - Preparing function sources ...
[9:47:15 PM] - Loading new function sources ...
[9:47:22 PM] - Starting function...
[9:47:22 PM] - WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1734144439.303879      20 init.cc:229] grpc_wait_for_shutdown_with_timeout() timed out.
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
E0000 00:00:1734144441.495104       7 init.cc:229] grpc_wait_for_shutdown_with_timeout() timed out.
/bin/sh: 2c3d685a15e9: not found
/bin/sh: 2c3d685a15e9: not found



What is CGP console? 2) What is the command you are issuing? 3) Do you have the required IAM permissions to deploy to Cloud Functions and are you using the correct identity? 4) Edit your post to add relevant information.


Thanks John. I hope this additional information is satisfactory

Those are just internal warnings of the grpc library, you can most likely ignore them, or just don't log their warnings if you want, alternatively see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78780089/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-annoying-terminal-warning-when-using-gemini-api for downgrading the lib so it doesnt log it in the first place.

Including the sh not found?
